# PHP doesn't recognize POST Upload done with HttpClient

Tags: java, php, file-upload

Java Code:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://localhost/SC/upload.php");

        FileBody bin = new FileBody(f3);

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("bin", bin);

        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        System.out
                .println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: "
                    + resEntity.getContentLength());
            System.out.println("Chunked?: " + resEntity.isChunked());
            System.out.println("Response: "
                    + EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
        if (resEntity != null) {
            resEntity.consumeContent();
        }
```

PHP Code:

```
    <?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }

print_r ($_FILES);
?>
```

Every time I run the Java Code, I always get:

> executing request POST http://localhost/SC/upload.php HTTP/1.1
> ----------------------------------------
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Response content length: 241
> Chunked?: false
> Response: Upload: 
> Type: 
> Size: 0 Kb
> Stored in: Array
> (
>     [bin] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => File.tar.lzma
>             [type] => 
>             [tmp_name] => 
>             [error] => 1
>             [size] => 0
>         )
>
> )

I've tested it with normal http upload (through webbrowser, same file) and it works.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: f3 is a File (that I KNOW exists, (/home/me/Desktop/File.tar.lzma))

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your Java, but I'm sure it's not your PHP.

Comment: can you tell us more about `f3`?

Comment: EDIT: f3 is a File (that I KNOW exists, (/home/me/Desktop/File.tar.lzma))

Comment: in such cases, if you understand the http protocol well enough, install wireshark and read the data transfer. youo will find the http post command has a something missing. wireshark is the best debugging tool for such situations.

Comment: I don't understand http that much, but I'll certainly try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it really WAS a php max file size problem, although it under the limit (2M), I didn't know that the java code was adding parts to the file (in the TAR code)

Increasing the limit fixed the problem.